# MacBookPro temperature inconsistency

Tags: bootcamp, hardware, windows, temperature

I have a 15" MacbookPro with a Windows 7 Bootcamp partition. I check the temperature when using Windows but I think it doesn't report the right temperature.
I shut down Windows with a temperature between the 70° and 80° degrees, then I immediately power on the laptop but this time I use OS X, when I log in it reports temperatures closes to 100° degrees.

It is possible that when I use Windows it is reporting wrong temperatures? If yes, what software should I use to monitor them correctly?

In OS X I use TG pro, in Windows I've tried many softwares but all of them reports the same data.

Answer (score 1):

In OSX you can also try many applications, one might give you the GPU or Motherboard temp instead of the CPU temp.

OSX temperature apps:

[atMonitor](http://www.atpurpose.com/atMonitor/) or
[smcFanControl](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/23049/smcfancontrol)

OSX might also take more resources than Windows. To minimize running apps, clear your startup items under Users in System Preferences, or check your Activity Monitor which shows your CPU% and Threads for each application, this way you can close apps that are using too much resources.